# Why my inheritance application is not working?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I'm doing a past school work and it is about a Microwave application with a child class, Clock. Somehow someWhere, I got confused about my codes and got lost totally. Could someone help me with these? Thanks!

[image]

First is the Clock class.

```
class Clock extends Microwave {

private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;

Clock()
{
    hour = 0;
    minute = 0;
    second = 0;     
}

Clock(int h, int m, int s)
{
    hour = h;
    minute = m;
    second = s;
}

public int getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

public int getMin()
{
    return minute;
}

public int getSec()
{
    return second;
}

public String toString()
{
    return (String.valueOf(second));
}

protected void tick()
{
    second++;

    if(hour == 23 && minute == 59 && second == 59)
    {
        hour = 0;
        minute = 0;
        second = 0;
    } else if(minute == 59 && second == 59)
    {
        hour++;
        minute = 0;
        second = 0;
    } else if(second == 59)
    {
        minute++;
        second = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Next will be the parent class, Microwave.

```
class Microwave {

private int maxPower;
private int currentPower;
private Clock theClock;

Microwave()
{
    maxPower = 500;
    currentPower = 500;
    theClock = new Clock();
}

Microwave(int maxp, Clock theClock)
{
    maxPower = maxp;
    currentPower = maxPower;
    theClock = new Clock();
}

public int getCurrentPower()
{
    return currentPower;
}

public int getMaxPower()
{
    return maxPower;
}

public String getTime()
{
    return "The time is " + theClock.getHour() + ":" + theClock.getMin() + ":" + theClock.getSec();
}

protected void cook(int p, int t)
{
    if(p < maxPower)
    {
        currentPower = p;
    } else
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        theClock.tick();
    }
}
}
```

Finally, the main method class.

```
class TestMicrowave
{
 public static void main(String []args)
 { 
    Clock  c = new Clock(14, 30,30);
    Microwave  m = new Microwave(750, c);
    System.out.println("The microwave is currently at " + 
                     m.getCurrentPower() + " watts and "+ m.getTime());


     m.cook(600,45);    // should advance time to  14:31:15

     System.out.println(m.getTime());

     m.cook(800,45);    // shoudln't cook as power > maxPower
     System.out.println(m.getTime());

 }
 }
```

From I think, there is something wrong with my getTime() method in the Microwave class but I have no idea what is wrong with it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the opposite? I mean, a microwave oven has a clock but a clock cannot cook :-)

Comment: Clock should not extend Microwave. A clock is a component of a microwave.

Comment: This is an awful assignment.  There is absolutely no reason that `Clock` should be extending `Microwave`.  A Microwave may contain a clock (which would "Compose" it, i.e. contain a member.), or implement some clock features though.

Comment: Yeah you guys have a great point there which I just realized. :S this work was dated a few years back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inheritance suggestion is rubbish, you should be composing the clock instead (a microwave may contain a clock, as your Microwave class is already written), so drop the `extends Microwave` from your Clock class.

Barring that issue, another issue is your CTORs:

```
Microwave()
{
    maxPower = 500;
    currentPower = 500;
    theClock = new Clock();
}

Microwave(int maxp, Clock theClock)
{
    maxPower = maxp;
    currentPower = maxPower;
    //theClock = new Clock(); // you're passing a reference to this already, so by using this call you replace it with a new instance via the default ctor of Clock().
    this.theClock = theClock;
}
```

Comment: hey hi erm you were saying i'm passing a reference already but which part is it that i'm passing to? is it the no parameter constructor? sorry i'm still a newbie hoping to learn from everyone and understand more about the whole thing. :)

Comment: When you declare `Clock c;` you just created a "reference" to a clock object, which is referring to nothing (or `null`) (picture this as a remote control that is unpaired from your TV).  `c` is not the actual object, it just allows you to control it.  So in your code, you use `Clock c = new Clock(14, 30, 30);` - here `c` is a reference (remote control) to the object you created (tv, in this ex).  When you pass that into `new Microwave`, you just gave it access to control/use the clock you made.

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 I think you are just confused with the diamond symbol. The diamond symbol means aggregation and composition. For inheritance you use a triangle symbol.

Answer (score 6):

The clock is NOT a child class. The microwave is COMPOSED of a clock. Remove the 'extends Microwave' from the Clock class.

There shouldn't be any inheritance in this design.

Comment: But i thought the classes supposed to have an association?

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 They do: a Microwave ***contains*** a clock :) That's the only association between a microwave and a clock, I suppose

Comment: subclasses provide a `IS-A` relationship, a Clock is NOT a microwave.  However microwaves `HAVE-A`Clock which is composition.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor that accepts a `Clock` argument is discarding it, so you are always starting with a zero clock.

```
Microwave(int maxp, Clock clock)
{
    maxPower = maxp;
    currentPower = maxPower;
    this.theClock = clock;
}
```

Comment: hi Dave, erm I don't really get it though. why is it that i'm starting with a zero clock? Cheers!